# Embedding YouTube Video in Trigger.io for iOS

Tags: youtube-api, trigger.io

Our html app occasionally embeds YouTube videos in the UI. We use a simple iframe to embed them.

When we put the app on our phones (iOS / iOS Simulator) the video opens in mobile Safari.

What's the right way to get the embedded YouTube videos to play within the app, and not launch Safari?

Comment: Whitelisting the youtube url in the app config got me part of the way, but now I'm getting a Webview error: `Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.youtube.com/embed/vEg4SEch27w?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.youtube.com/embed/vEg4SEch27w?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since YouTube redirects you to its https:// protocol site, you need to whitelist `https://youtube.com` -- just whitelisting `http://youtube.com` is not enough.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem but cannot find any place or documentation on whitelisting URLs in trigger. How is that done?

Comment: Assuming you're using the TriggerToolkit GUI, go to the Config - App form and add the URLs you want to whitelist to the `trusted urls` field.